# npm: игнорировать обновление конкретного модуля

Tags: node.js, npm

Существует некий модуль "ejs-mate", установленный в проект nodejs при помощи  менеджера npm. В исходники модуля мне пришлось внести некие изменения для более корректной его работы. Однако в проекте имеется ряд других модулей, и ведется активная разработка, файл package.json пополняется новыми.

Вопрос: не откатится ли исходный код "ejs-mate" при npm update/install, затерев все мои изменения? Если да, что мне делать? Написать шелл скрипт, который бы по завершении активности npm вносил изменения в ejs-mate? Создать копию ejs-mate с моими настройками, и разместить его в репозитории npm под другим именем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ситуация, когда приходится править исходники существующих модулей довольно часто встречается на практике (причем не только в экосистеме node.js).

Если изменения, что вы сделали, могут быть полезны кому-то кроме вас, нужно оправить pull-request разработчику модуля. Если изменения будут приняты -- ваша проблема перестанет существовать сама собой.

Если же изменения носят локальный, незначительный характер, или же автор модуля отказался их принять, вам придется использовать вашу измененную версию модуля.

Самый простой способ: указать в package.json вместо версии "проблемного" модуля ссылку на репозиторий с его измененными исходными кодами. Например так:

```
"dependencies" : {
    "ejs-mate" : "git://github.com/user/ejs-mate.git#commit-ish"
}
```

Однако, нужно понимать, что это измененная версия модуля будет использоваться только в вашем коде и не повлияют на зависимости сторонних модулей.

---

Теперь скажу несколько слов о предложенных вами вариантах решения проблем.

> Написать шелл скрипт, который бы по завершении активности npm вносил изменения в ejs-mate?

Хотя формально вы можете так сделать, но *лучше даже не думать* о подобных решениях и вот почему.

NPM 3 использует *одну* копию модуля, если во всех зависящих от него модулях указана одна и та же версия. Это означает, что если вы после `npm install`/`npm update` примените патч (нужный вашему проекту) к модулю `foo@3.0.0` а модуль `bar@0.2.0` зависит от `foo@3.0.0`, то `bar` будет *работать с пропатченной* версией `foo`!

Таким образом, вы можете очень легко порушить работоспособность одной из зависимостей, при этом выявить где именно ошибка будет невероятно сложно.

> Создать копию ejs-mate с моими настройками, и разместить его в репозитории npm под другим именем?

Так делать *категорически* нельзя. Если каждый пользователь npm будет так делать, то очень скоро основной репозиторий модулей превратится в помойку. Если очень хочется хранить вашу измененную версию модуля в именно репозитории, то лучше использовать свой собственный npm репозиторий. В сети есть большое количество статей о том, как его развернуть. ([Одна из подобных статей.](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository))